# Call "new" on my class in my libs after webpack.js build

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I try to figuring out how to call new after webpack.js build final index.js
I build my own lib, and it's work. But now I want to minify and use it in other project.

myLib.js

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(milan) {
        this.milan = milan;
    }

    loging(options) {
        console.log('finaly')
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import MyClass from "./myLib";

export {MyClass};
```

my index.min.js looks like this.

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: "development").
 * This devtool is not neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
 * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: "production" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).
 */
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./src/js/dropdown.js":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** ./src/js/dropdown.js ***!
  \****************************/
/*! namespace exports */
/*! export default [provided] [no usage info] [missing usage info prevents renaming] */
/*! other exports [not provided] [no usage info] */
/*! runtime requirements: __webpack_require__.r, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__.d, __webpack_require__.* */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"default\": () => /* binding */ Dropdown\n/* harmony export */ });\nfunction _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError(\"Cannot call a class as a function\"); } }\n\nfunction _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if (\"value\" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }\n\nfunction _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }\n\nvar Dropdown = /*#__PURE__*/function () {\n  function Dropdown(dropdownObject) {\n    _classCallCheck(this, Dropdown);\n\n    this.dropdownObject = dropdownObject;\n    this.values = null;\n    this.allowSearch = false;\n    this.allowMultiple = false;\n  }\n\n  _createClass(Dropdown, [{\n    key: \"selectable\",\n    value: function selectable(options) {\n      var _this2 = this;\n\n      if (options !== undefined) {\n        this.allowSearch = options.allowSearch;\n        this.allowMultiple = options.allowMultiple;\n      }\n\n      var dropdownObject = this.dropdownObject;\n      var dropdownMenu = this.dropdownObject.querySelector('.menu');\n      var items = dropdownMenu.getElementsByClassName('item');\n      items = Array.from(items);\n      var text = this.dropdownObject.querySelector('.text');\n      var input = null;\n      var filter = '';\n\n      if (this.allowMultiple) {\n        this.values = [];\n        this.dropdownObject.classList.add('dropdown_multiple');\n      }\n\n      var filtering = function filtering() {\n        text.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input type=\"text\" class=\"dropdown_input\">');\n        input = dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input');\n        input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {\n          _this2.dropdownObject.classList.add('active');\n\n          dropdownMenu.classList.add('visible');\n          filter = input.value.toLowerCase();\n          var inputWidth = (filter.length + 8) * 8;\n          _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input').style.width = inputWidth + \"px\";\n\n          if (filter === '') {\n            input.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.remove('filtered');\n          } else {\n            input.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.add('filtered');\n          }\n\n          var tmpItems = Array.from(items);\n\n          if (Array.isArray(_this2.values)) {\n            _this2.values.map(function (selected) {\n              var _loop = function _loop(_i) {\n                if (selected === items[_i].getAttribute('data-value')) {\n                  tmpItems = tmpItems.filter(function (tmpItem) {\n                    return tmpItem !== items[_i];\n                  });\n                }\n              };\n\n              for (var _i = 0; _i < items.length; _i++) {\n                _loop(_i);\n              }\n            });\n          }\n\n          tmpItems.map(function (tmpItem) {\n            var selectTempText = tmpItem.textContent;\n\n            if (selectTempText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {\n              for (var _i2 = 0; _i2 < items.length; _i2++) {\n                if (tmpItem === items[_i2]) {\n                  items[_i2].classList.remove('filtered');\n                }\n              }\n            } else {\n              for (var _i3 = 0; _i3 < items.length; _i3++) {\n                if (tmpItem === items[_i3]) {\n                  items[_i3].classList.add('filtered');\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          });\n          var i = 0;\n          items.map(function (item) {\n            if (item.classList.contains('filtered')) {\n              i++;\n            }\n          });\n          var notFound = dropdownMenu.querySelector('.message');\n\n          if (items.length === i) {\n            if (notFound === null) {\n              var div = document.createElement('div');\n              div.classList.add('message');\n\n              var _text = document.createTextNode('No results found.');\n\n              div.appendChild(_text);\n              dropdownMenu.appendChild(div);\n            }\n          } else {\n            if (notFound !== null) {\n              dropdownMenu.removeChild(notFound);\n            }\n          }\n        });\n      };\n\n      if (this.allowSearch) {\n        filtering();\n        this.dropdownObject.classList.add('dropdown_search');\n      }\n\n      var openMenuHandler = function openMenuHandler() {\n        var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');\n\n        for (var _i4 = 0; _i4 < dropdowns.length; _i4++) {\n          if (dropdownObject !== dropdowns[_i4]) {\n            dropdowns[_i4].classList.remove('active');\n\n            dropdowns[_i4].querySelector('.menu').classList.remove('visible');\n          }\n        }\n\n        var i = 0;\n        items.map(function (item) {\n          if (item.classList.contains('filtered')) {\n            i++;\n          }\n        });\n\n        if (_this2.allowSearch) {\n          _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input').focus();\n        }\n\n        if (!_this2.allowSearch && !_this2.allowMultiple) {\n          _this2.dropdownObject.classList.toggle('active');\n\n          dropdownMenu.classList.toggle('visible');\n        } else {\n          _this2.dropdownObject.classList.add('active');\n\n          dropdownMenu.classList.add('visible');\n          var tmpItems = Array.from(items);\n\n          if (Array.isArray(_this2.values)) {\n            _this2.values.map(function (selected) {\n              var _loop2 = function _loop2(_i5) {\n                if (selected === items[_i5].getAttribute('data-value')) {\n                  tmpItems = tmpItems.filter(function (tmpItem) {\n                    return tmpItem !== items[_i5];\n                  });\n                }\n              };\n\n              for (var _i5 = 0; _i5 < items.length; _i5++) {\n                _loop2(_i5);\n              }\n            });\n          }\n\n          var message = _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.message');\n\n          if (message !== null) {\n            message.remove();\n          }\n\n          for (var _i6 = 0; _i6 < items.length; _i6++) {\n            items[_i6].classList.add('filtered');\n          }\n\n          if (filter === '') {\n            tmpItems.map(function (tmpItem) {\n              for (var _i7 = 0; _i7 < items.length; _i7++) {\n                if (tmpItem === items[_i7]) {\n                  items[_i7].classList.remove('filtered');\n                }\n              }\n            });\n          } else {\n            if (items.length === i) {\n              var div = document.createElement('div');\n              div.classList.add('message');\n\n              var _text2 = document.createTextNode('No results found.');\n\n              div.appendChild(_text2);\n              dropdownMenu.appendChild(div);\n            }\n\n            tmpItems.map(function (tmpItem) {\n              var selectTempText = tmpItem.textContent;\n\n              if (selectTempText.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {\n                for (var _i8 = 0; _i8 < items.length; _i8++) {\n                  if (tmpItem === items[_i8]) {\n                    items[_i8].classList.remove('filtered');\n                  }\n                }\n              } else {\n                for (var _i9 = 0; _i9 < items.length; _i9++) {\n                  if (tmpItem === items[_i9]) {\n                    items[_i9].classList.add('filtered');\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            });\n          }\n        }\n      };\n\n      this.dropdownObject.addEventListener('click', function (e) {\n        e.stopPropagation();\n        openMenuHandler();\n      });\n      document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {\n        var message = _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.message');\n\n        if (message !== null) {\n          message.remove();\n        }\n\n        if (_this2.allowSearch) {\n          input.value = '';\n          filter = '';\n\n          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {\n            items[i].classList.remove('filtered');\n          }\n\n          input.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.remove('filtered');\n        }\n\n        if (_this2.allowSearch && _this2.allowMultiple) {\n          _this2.values.map(function (selected) {\n            for (var _i10 = 0; _i10 < items.length; _i10++) {\n              if (selected === items[_i10].getAttribute('data-value')) {\n                items[_i10].classList.add('filtered');\n              }\n            }\n          });\n        }\n\n        if (e.target !== dropdownObject) {\n          dropdownObject.classList.remove('active');\n          dropdownMenu.classList.remove('visible');\n\n          if (_this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input') !== null) {\n            _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input').style.width = 16 + \"px\";\n          }\n        }\n      });\n\n      var removeItemHandler = function removeItemHandler() {\n        var removeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times');\n\n        for (var i = 0; i < removeButtons.length; i++) {\n          removeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {\n            e.target.parentNode.remove();\n\n            for (var _i11 = 0; _i11 < items.length; _i11++) {\n              if (items[_i11].getAttribute('data-value') === e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value')) {\n                items[_i11].classList.remove('filtered');\n\n                _this2.values = _this2.values.filter(function (value) {\n                  return value !== e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-value');\n                });\n              }\n            }\n\n            var i = 1;\n            items.map(function (item) {\n              if (item.classList.contains('filtered')) {\n                i++;\n              }\n            });\n\n            if (items.length === i) {\n              var message = _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.message');\n\n              if (message !== null) {\n                message.remove();\n              }\n            }\n          });\n        }\n      };\n\n      var addItemsHandler = function addItemsHandler(e) {\n        var _this = e.target;\n\n        if (_this2.allowMultiple) {\n          _this2.values.push(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'));\n\n          _this.classList.add('filtered');\n\n          var child = _this.cloneNode(true);\n\n          var nodePLace = dropdownObject.childNodes.length;\n          dropdownObject.insertBefore(child, dropdownObject.childNodes[nodePLace - 5]);\n          child.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', \"<i class=\\\"fas fa-times\\\"></i>\");\n          child.classList.add('label');\n          var i = 0;\n          items.map(function (item) {\n            if (item.classList.contains('filtered')) {\n              i++;\n            }\n          });\n\n          if (items.length === i) {\n            _this2.dropdownObject.classList.remove('active');\n\n            dropdownMenu.classList.remove('visible');\n          }\n\n          removeItemHandler();\n        } else {\n          _this2.values = _this.getAttribute('data-value');\n\n          _this.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(function (e) {\n            return e.classList.remove('selected');\n          });\n\n          _this.classList.add('selected');\n\n          dropdownObject.classList.remove('active');\n          dropdownMenu.classList.remove('visible');\n          text.innerHTML = \"\";\n\n          var _child = _this.cloneNode(true);\n\n          text.appendChild(_child);\n        }\n\n        if (_this2.allowSearch) {\n          input.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.remove('filtered');\n          input.value = '';\n          filter = '';\n\n          _this2.dropdownObject.querySelector('.dropdown_input').focus();\n        }\n      };\n\n      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {\n        items[i].addEventListener(\"click\", function (e) {\n          e.stopPropagation();\n          addItemsHandler(e);\n        });\n      }\n    }\n  }, {\n    key: \"getValue\",\n    value: function getValue() {\n      return this.values;\n    }\n  }]);\n\n  return Dropdown;\n}();\n\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://imp_design/./src/js/dropdown.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/js/index.js":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./src/js/index.js ***!
  \*************************/
/*! namespace exports */
/*! export Dropdown [provided] [no usage info] [missing usage info prevents renaming] -> ./src/js/dropdown.js .default */
/*! other exports [not provided] [no usage info] */
/*! runtime requirements: __webpack_require__, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__.d, __webpack_require__.r, __webpack_require__.* */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"Dropdown\": () => /* reexport safe */ _dropdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default\n/* harmony export */ });\n/* harmony import */ var _dropdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./dropdown */ \"./src/js/dropdown.js\");\n\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://imp_design/./src/js/index.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/scss/imp_design.scss":
/*!**********************************!*\
  !*** ./src/scss/imp_design.scss ***!
  \**********************************/
/*! namespace exports */
/*! exports [not provided] [no usage info] */
/*! runtime requirements: __webpack_require__.r, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__.* */
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://imp_design/./src/scss/imp_design.scss?");

/***/ })

/******/    });
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};
/******/    
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(__webpack_module_cache__[moduleId]) {
/******/            return __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
/******/            // no module.id needed
/******/            // no module.loaded needed
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/    
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        __webpack_modules__[moduleId](module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/    
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/define property getters */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define getter functions for harmony exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.d = (exports, definition) => {
/******/            for(var key in definition) {
/******/                if(__webpack_require__.o(definition, key) && !__webpack_require__.o(exports, key)) {
/******/                    Object.defineProperty(exports, key, { enumerable: true, get: definition[key] });
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/hasOwnProperty shorthand */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.o = (obj, prop) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // startup
/******/    // Load entry module
/******/    __webpack_require__("./src/scss/imp_design.scss");
/******/    // This entry module used 'exports' so it can't be inlined
/******/    __webpack_require__("./src/js/index.js");
/******/    __webpack_require__("./src/js/dropdown.js");
/******/ })()
;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: [
            './src/scss/imp_design.scss',
            './src/js/index.js',
            './src/js/Mylib.js'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    publicPath: './',
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css'
        })
    ]
}
```

some.js

```
 import MyClas from 'index.min.js'
 let myClass = new MyClass("someValue");
 myClass.loging();
```

And error from console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined".

I try with require and

```
  library: 'webpackNumbers',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
```

Of Course everything works nice without webpack. But I want now to minimize code and no luck.

Comment: "*index.html or anywhere in my app where I import index.js*" - well, where did you `import` it?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. I build my lib to use/import in other .js files. import MyClass from "./index.min.js""; and then use it  let myClass = new MyClass("someValue"); So in index.html I import <script src="index.min.js"></script>
and then use it. Lib working but now i need to minify and use it in other project.

Comment: `import MyClass from "./index.min.js"` and `<script src="index.min.js">` are doing very different things.

Comment: Can I get help only for import MyClass from "./index.min.js", and in that .js just use it multiple times let myClass = new MyClass("someValue"); let myClass2 = new MyClass("someValue"); I dont need it in <script src="index.min.js"> I don't have MyClass anywhere in index.min.js. So webpack just igonre it.

Comment: I update my question. Lib is big, and this is not lib. So I just try to get this simple example to work. Then I will be applied to my code.